How to fix: “userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) is not called”?
When I send notification from Firebase Console, it comes to the app, but when I tap on the notification banner, function userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) should be called and print the text "didReceive method is called", but no such text appears. What is wrong with my code?
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseFirestore


let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds 


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
              if granted {
                  print("User notifications are allowed.")
              } else {
                  print("User notifications are not allowed.")
      } }
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

          return true
  }
}


extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("didReceive method is called")
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("userInfo is ", userInfo)

        if let title = userInfo["title"] as? String,
           let message = userInfo["message"] as? String {
            // Create the PushNotificationView with the received title and message
            let contentView = PushNotificationView(message: message, title: title)
            print("__________________ FUNCTION userNotificationCenter_______________")
            print("Message is: ", message)
            pushMessage = message
            print("Title is: ", title)

            // Get the main window scene
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                // Access the relevant window from the window scene
                if let window = windowScene.windows.first {
                    // Set the root view controller of the window to display the PushNotificationView
                    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Title and message could not be retrieved")
        }

        completionHandler() // Call the completion handler when finished processing
    }
}


extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

      let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
      )
        if let fcmToken = fcmToken  {
            deviceToken = fcmToken}
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

}

@main
struct PirouetteApp: App {
    
    // register app delegate
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            if let user = AuthService.shared.currentUser {
                if user.uid == adminID || user.uid == admin2ID {
                    AdminOrderView()
                } else {
                    let viewModel = MainTabBarViewModel(user: user)
                    MainTabBar(viewModel: viewModel)
               
                }
            } else {
                AuthView()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                   if newPhase == .active {
                       // Clear badge count when app becomes active
                       UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                   }
               }             
    }
}

I tried to do it by myself

in your Project TARGETS Signing & Capabilities have you added the capability Push Notifications ?

Hello, Workingdog. Thank you for supporting Ukraine. I am a Ukrainian by the way. Yes, Push notification is added to the capabilities. I could not get notification otherwise. Push notifications come to the app, but I cannot get data from them, because didReceive method is not called.

It is a mystic. Method willPresent notification works fine when application is on foreground, but method didReceive response is not called when the app is on background. This small easy code is not called:
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
print("didReceive method is called")
}

I have found the problem. The bug is with Xcode. I restarted my laptop and didReceive still is not called with Emulator but it starts work with real device.

I have found the problem. The bug is with Xcode. I restarted my laptop and didReceive still is not called with Emulator but it starts work with real device.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
